# 2-Phase Commit Algorithm: When does the Coordinator/Master save its own data?

Tags: database, algorithm, transactions, protocols, distributed-computing

I've read multiple articles online about 2PC and none of them explain this. Let's say we have 3 dbs A,B,C and each has `value(key = x) = 55`. We want a transaction where the value for key `x` is changed to `56`, let's say. This write request lands on A and needs to be propagated to B and C, in an all-or-nothing fashion.

I guess A could update it's own data after committing the transaction and getting acknowledgement from B and C; then A could consider the transaction done. But, this means there's this period of time where B and C don't know that the transaction is done. A client who reads `x` from B would see value `56`, while the value read at the same time from A would be `55`. The next idea is "Well, have B wait to commit until A has acknowledged that it received B's acknowledgement," but then you're in the reverse situation (A has committed its local changes and B has not).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol#Message_flow explains this. Look for the `*`. `B` and `C` write the transaction and rollback in phase 1. The coordinator writes its log upon completing voting. Then `B` and `C` save the commit in phrase 2. If there is a failure, on recover `A`'s log always has the definitive outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Two phase is all or nothing, with definition if one commits, all will eventually commit, if one aborts all will eventually abort. It is about  Atomicity, what you are talking is Isolation, telling what others can see when transaction is in progress.

Depending on Isolation level, A, B and C can lock the record preventing any read, either when the write came is or when commit started, or never (case you covered).